# Scala generic methods that take functions

Tags: scala, generics

I have a method:

```
private def foo(f: => Future[Any]): Future[Any] = {
    //code, code, code
    //function return same result as function that taken
}
```

This works well but I need to use this in different part of my project with different types, and there are some restrictions.
If I need to call some method of a type that I use, then it is not available, without casting.

For example:

```
if(foo("abacaba").containsSlice("dabacaba")){...}

if(foo(15) > 55){...}
```

Is there way to create generic function, to handle all these cases?

Comment: Like `Future[A]` or just some generic type `A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that the return type of the function you are getting (that might be anything) is the same type your function is returning.

```
private def foo[T](f: => Future[T]): Future[T] = {
    //code, code, code
    //function return same result as function that taken
}
```

I don't think it is really necessary to say `[T <: Any]` since everything is of type `Any`

Answer (score 0):

You already have it defined in Scala's library as `scala.Function0`
You actually have also traits that define functions that get parameters as Function1 - Function22.

This is the source code for `Function0` -

```
trait Function0[@specialized(Specializable.Primitives) +R] extends AnyRef { self =>
  /** Apply the body of this function to the arguments.
   *  @return   the result of function application.
   */
  def apply(): R

  override def toString() = "<function0>"
}
```

If you want to get Future as a param you can write very similar Trait for Future.